# EGalax touchscreen no input on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: touchscreen, xinput

I'm trying a Egalax touchscreen to  work for a TPV on Ubuntu 18.04, but everything I tried didnt work at all. I tried to make it work with "calibrate touchscreen" as Ubuntu seems to detect the screen correctly, but no input at all from calibration.
I tried with the Egalax driver as this tutorial:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touchscreen

And This other:
[eGalax Touchscreen Configuration Ubuntu 14.04LTS](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1G4oD6Y8vlyNHW6wJT89pxcjWHoETLLT-SEoAIW6_7Xc/pub)

But no luck. Nothing happens when I touch the screen.
Here is my lsusb:

```
> tpv@tpv-desktop:~$ lsusb
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 002: ID 116f:c108 Silicon 10 Technology Corp. Flash Card Reader
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 005: ID 0eef:0001 D-WAV Scientific Co., Ltd eGalax TouchScreen
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 046d:c517 Logitech, Inc. LX710 Cordless Desktop Laser
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 248a:8367  
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 011 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 010 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

xinput -list

```
 xinput -list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Telink Wireless Receiver                  id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ eGalax Inc. USB TouchController           id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Telink Wireless Receiver                  id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Telink Wireless Receiver                  id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

and

```
xinput -list-props 12
Device 'eGalax Inc. USB TouchController':
    Device Enabled (150):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (152): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Calibration Matrix (307):  1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Calibration Matrix Default (308):  1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (272): 1, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (273):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (274):    0, 0
    Device Node (275):  "/dev/input/event13"
    Device Product ID (276):    3823, 1
```

Any help to make a Egalax touchscreen to work with Ubuntu 18.04 whould be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I am having the exact same problem, sunk a few days into this now. I am keen for some help ....

Comment: @hatterman check my answer

Comment: @xinthose I had already sunk hours into trying with that driver. Not working for me.

Answer (score 2):

This is working on 5 of my machines and has the advantage that you can stop and start the touchscreen with systemD (systemctl status eGTouch.service)

---

Download the latest touchscreen driver from eGalax
Untar the files

```
tar xvzf eGTouch_v2.5.5814.L-x
```

Run setup

```
sudo ./setup.sh
```

Create the SystemD .service file.

```
sudo systemctl edit --force --full eGTouch.service
```

Paste the following unit file modification

```
#######################################################
#### eGalax Touch Unit File for auto start on boot ####
#######################################################
[Unit]
Documentation=man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
SourcePath=/usr/bin/eGTouchD
DefaultDependencies=no
Before=sysinit.target
After=apparmor.service

[Service]
Type=forking
Restart=always
RestartSec=5
StartLimitInterval=60s
StartLimitBurst=3
TimeoutSec=0
IgnoreSIGPIPE=no
KillMode=process
GuessMainPID=no
RemainAfterExit=no
User=root
Group=root
ExecStart=/usr/bin/eGTouchD start
ExecReload=/usr/bin/eGTouchD restart
ExecStop=/usr/bin/eGTouchD stop

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
################################################
```

Then enable it

```
sudo systemctl enable eGTouch.service
```

Then restart it

```
sudo systemctl restart eGTouch.service
```

Then reboot

```
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Please note that the eGTouch_v2.5.6722.L-x.tar.gz driver is Broken! It throws the following error on a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04LTS.

(EE) event14 - eGalaxTouch Virtual Device for Single: kernel bug: device has min == max on ABS_TILT_X

I've reported this to the vendor. Hopefully they will come up with an updated driver soon.

Comment: 've located the problem it's is in the the eGTouchD binary file.
I installed the 2.5.6722.L-x driver 
before rebooting I replaced the eGTouchD binary with the v2.5.5814 version of eGTouchD binary in
/usr/local/eGTouch64withX/eGTouchD

rebooted. Now the touchscreen works properly.

Comment: It looks to me like setup.sh already creates the systemd service. It creates a service called "eGTouchD.service". Using your instructions makes it so there are two services. Is this the intended result? 
Also, these instructions are the same as listed here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1G4oD6Y8vlyNHW6wJT89pxcjWHoETLLT-SEoAIW6_7Xc/pub

Comment: @EvandelaCruz the default installed service fails to work on my Ubuntu, which is why I just run the script as root

Answer (score 1):

My solution was the following. (USB connection, Ubuntu 18.04, 64 bits)

What I did first was identify the driver:

```
xinput list
```

and then

1. Download and install the eGTouch driver.

   ```
   wget https://www.eeti.com/touch_driver/Linux/20210716/eGTouch_v2.5.10206.L-x.tar.gz
   ```
2. Extract the tarball

   ```
   tar zxvf eGTouch_v2.5.10206.L-x.tar.gz
   ```
3. Run `setup.sh` as root.

   ```
   cd eGTouch_v2.5.10206.L-x
   sudo ./setup.sh
   ```
4. Next, `cd` to `/usr/bin` and run `./eGTouchU`

   ```
   cd /usr/bin
   sudo ./eGTouchU
   ```
5. This command opens the eGTouch GUI.
6. Go to the **Tool** tab.
7. Click **Clear Parameter** and click the four points on the screen.

   [image: eGTouch screenshot]

   Problem solved.

Comment: Hi - and thanks for this.  If this can be converted to english either by yourself or a member of the community then please do edit and update.  cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working for me.  (USB connection, Ubuntu 18.04 64-bit)

1. [Download and install the eGTouch driver](https://www.eeti.com/drivers_Linux.html).  Unpack the `.tar.gz` and run `setup.sh` as root. Answer the prompts according to your needs.
2. Run this as root: `crontab -e`
3. Add this line: `@reboot /etc/init.d/eGTouch.sh`

- run this script at boot as root, will not work otherwise

4. `reboot`

Comment: Why start it by cron?

Comment: @Pilot6 it is the easiest way to run a script as root at time of bootup on Linux

Comment: No, it is not nether the easiest, not the best way.

Comment: @Pilot6 that is your opinion; this method works best for my application at the moment

Answer (score 0):

You can manually setup a mapping of the USB touch to X11:

1. Use "xrandr" to identify the touchscreen crtc name, such as "DP-1"
2. Use "xinput --list --name-only" to get USB touch name
3. Use "xinput --map-to-output" to map the two.

My system is Ubuntu 16, Elo touchscreen as primary monitor.

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 476mm x 268mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1680x1050     59.95  
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 476mm x 267mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94    50.00  
   1600x900      60.00
```

```
$ xinput --list --name-only
Virtual core pointer
Virtual core XTEST pointer
PixArt Dell MS116 USB Optical Mouse
HP USB Slim Keyboard
Elo multi-touch digitizer - 0 - 0eef:7200
Virtual core keyboard
Virtual core XTEST keyboard
Power Button
```

Final setup command. I placed it in "~/.xprofile".

```
xinput --map-to-output "Elo multi-touch digitizer - 0 - 0eef:7200" DP-1
```