# touchpad doesnt work :( exceptional problem

Tags: touchpad

maybe someone will inspire? :) Well, we have a small problem - the patient is akoya (touch screen). Of course, Linux is necessary for work - here, unfortunately, there is a problem. Due to the fact that the screen is touch, linux classifies this screen as a touchpad (the touchpad does not work). We've tried many ways, but it can't be bypassed for now - it's still the touch screen that plays the role of the touchpad. Has anyone encountered a similar problem? I greet and have a nice evening

Comment: What is the model of your computer?

Comment: medion akoya P7631T

Comment: That's not a common laptop. Please run the command `xinput list` and post the output in your question so it becomes clear what exact pointing devices you have.

Comment: https://zapodaj.net/e974434acc961.png.html

Comment: we tried with everything and none works...

Comment: Have you tried to manually download and install eGalax drivers? See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1088353/egalax-touchscreen-no-input-on-ubuntu-18-04 for details. You can download the drivers here http://www.eeti.com/drivers_Linux.html

Comment: unfortunately yes i tried

Comment: Well, xinput doesn’t recognize your touchpad as a touchpad, so it is not being listed as pointing device. All it says in there is a mouse and a touchscreen that supposedly works. If your problem is that you need the touchpad to work, you need to find what device this is. So please run the commands `lsusb` and `lspci` to share what other devices you have present on your machine.

Comment: https://zapodaj.net/e004778060140.png.html

Comment: So there’s nothing in those lists that would indicate you have a touchpad connected. If this touchpad works in Windows, boot into windows, go to device manager, and search for the touchpad device. Then copy it’s vendor ID and device ID which looks like two four character hex strings. If you don’t know how to do that follow this link. https://www.keysight.com/main/editorial.jspx?ckey=2039700&&cc=US&lc=eng. This information is critical in identifying your touchpad hardware.

Comment: It could also be that the physical connection of the touchpad cable has come loose. Maybe you can open up the laptop and double check that.

Comment: Also for more complete information, run `sudo lshw` to list every single hardware in your laptop. This will return a very long list so you can put it either in the question or a pastebin.